# How to show styles in the editor tinymce react

Tags: reactjs, tinymce

if i put a html page with `<style>` tags I only get the bare html.

this is the html page that works if i open with chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: "Segoe UI", "Lucida Sans", sans-serif;
      }

      .blue-box {
        background-color: #dd3e05;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 22px;
        width: 537px;
        height: 380px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }

      .second-border {
        padding: 8px 8px 4px;
      }

      .image {
        width: 440px;
        height: 36px;
      }

      .first-text {
        width: 475px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 12px 0px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1rem;
      }

      .first-input {
        width: 435px;
        height: 26px;
        margin: 20px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 1rem;
      }

      .input-1 {
        float: right;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        padding: 0;
        width: 235px;
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 35px;
      }

      .ZmPasswordRecoveryButton .ZButtonBorder {
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        padding: 2px;
      }

      .ZToolbarButtonBorder,
      .ZButtonBorder {
        border-collapse: separate;
      }

      .ZButtonBorder {
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        height: 100%;
        background: #fff;
      }

      .ZWidgetTable {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      table {
        display: table;
        border-collapse: separate;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-indent: initial;
        border-spacing: 2px;
        border-color: gray;
      }

      .ZmPasswordRecoveryButton {
        background-color: #007cc3;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #fff;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin: 0 0.4em;
      }

      TD {
        border-width: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      td {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: inherit;
      }

      TABLE {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border-spacing: 0;
        border-width: 0;
      }

      P,
      TH,
      TD,
      DIV,
      SELECT,
      INPUT[type=text],
      INPUT[type=password],
      INPUT[type=file],
      TEXTAREA,
      BUTTON {
        font-size: 1rem;
      }

      p {
        display: block;
        margin-block-start: 1em;
        margin-block-end: 1em;
        margin-inline-start: 0px;
        margin-inline-end: 0px;
      }
    </style>
    <title>password</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="" autocomplete="off" method="POST" name="zmbForm"><input type="hidden"
        value="https://mail.comunecavallinotreporti.it/public/PasswordRecovery.jsp" />
      <div class="blue-box">
        <div class="second-border">

          <div class="first-text">
            <p>Inserisci il tuo nome utente in modo che possiamo recuperare l’email di recupero che hai registrato.<br />
          </div>

          <div class="first-input"> 
            <p>Vecchia password:</p>
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-1" id="user" name="oldpassword" size="35" type="password" />
          </div>

          <div class="first-input"> 
            <p>Nuova password:</p>
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-1" id="password" size="35" type="password" name="newpassword" />
          </div>

          <div class="first-input"> 
            <p>Conferma nuova password:</p>
            <input autocomplete="off" class="input-1" id="password2" size="35" type="password" name="newpassword2" />
          </div>

          <table role="presentation" width="100%">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td align="left">
                  <table role="presentation">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td id="Torna a Accedi_DWT2"
                          onclick="window.location.href = ''">
                          <div class="ZmPasswordRecoveryButton ZFocused" id="DWT9_button6" parentid="DWT9" role="button"
                            style="position: static; overflow: visible; display: block;" tabindex="0">
                            <table cellspacing="0" class="ZWidgetTable ZButtonTable ZButtonBorder" role="presentation"
                              style="table-layout:auto;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="ZLeftIcon ZWidgetIcon" id="DWT9_button6_left_icon"> </td>
                                  <td class="ZWidgetTitle" id="DWT9_button6_title">Torna a Accedi</td>
                                  <td class="ZRightIcon ZWidgetIcon" id="DWT9_button6_right_icon"> </td>
                                  <td class="ZDropDown" id="DWT9_button6_dropdown"> </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
                <td align="right">
                  <table role="presentation">
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td id="Sottoscrivi_DWT3" onclick="document.zmbForm.submit()">
                          <div aria-disabled="true" class="ZmPasswordRecoveryButton ZDisabled" id="DWT9_button7"
                            parentid="DWT9" role="button" style="position: static; overflow: visible; display: block;"
                            tabindex="0">
                            <table cellspacing="0" class="ZWidgetTable ZButtonTable ZButtonBorder" role="presentation"
                              style="table-layout:auto;">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="ZLeftIcon ZWidgetIcon" id="DWT9_button7_left_icon"> </td>
                                  <td class="ZWidgetTitle" id="DWT9_button7_title">Invia</td>
                                  <td class="ZRightIcon ZWidgetIcon" id="DWT9_button7_right_icon"> </td>
                                  <td class="ZDropDown" id="DWT9_button7_dropdown"> </td>
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

on web i see it like this

[image]

instead in the tinymce editor and then if i open what that editor saves i see it like this

[image]

here is my editor code

```
<Editor
  apiKey="xongwasdaybtmwmtmucmnpw9quu1ccq038zp67e4vm0i"
  onInit={(evt, editor) => { htmlRef.current = editor; }}
  initialValue={land.sms_landing_html}
  init={{
    height: 500,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar: 'undo redo | formatselect | '
      + 'bold italic backcolor | alignleft aligncenter '
      + 'alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | '
      + 'removeformat | help',
    valid_children: '+body[style], +head[style]',
    inline_styles: true,
  }}
/>
```

and then I get the contet like this

```js
htmlRef.current.getContent({ format: 'text' })
```

I get it like text because if it was html it would add a `"<p>"` at the beginning and a `"</p>"` at the end

if somone knows how to show styles and save them it would be very good thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your tinyMCE component, you can pass it a "content_css" props, where you can define all the style you want for your editor.
(https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/tinymce-css-and-custom-styles/)

That said, I suggest you to keep default tinyMCE style values, and in your webpage add custom style for what you want to be displayed.

Comment: but i would like to have get the styles from the html tag <styles> inside the html code because i need it from there

Comment: and i don't want to change the editor styles but the styles of what appear in the editor, and it would need to get them from the <style> tag

Comment: I don't think this is something you should do, what are you trying to achieve with your editor ?